# How to run a script only once in a day in a Chrome extention

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension that redirects to a webpage when someone visits a specific site. But, I want this to open a web page only once in a day, not every time.

This is what I'm using:

```js
function showOnceInADay() {
    var user = getCookie("user");
    if (user != "") {} else {
        // content.js
        window.open('http://google.com')
    }
}
```

But, it's not working.

**Here is the code which I want to run.**

```
window.open ('http://google.com')
```

Here's the *manifest.json* file

```json
 {
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "My Cool Extension",
     "version": "0.1",

     "content_scripts": [{
         "matches": [
             "https://www.snapdeal.com/"
         ],
         "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "content.js"]
     }],

     "browser_action": {
         "default_icon": "icon.png"
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: How is `showOnceInADay()` being called.  You define the function, but there is nothing that indicates it is ever called.

Comment: showOnceInADay() is in content.js file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the **jQuery Cookie** plugin installed:

```
function showOnceInADay(){
    var user = $.cookie("user"),
        day = $.cookie("day");
    var d = new Date();
    var checkDay = d.getDate();
    if (user === "" && checkDay != day) {
        // content
        window.open ('http://google.com');
        $.cookie("day", checkDay);
    }
}
```

You can get the current date using the `Date()`; method, and then crosscheck that with the current date.

If they do not match and the user is defined, it will open `http://www.google.com/` and set the day cookie to the new date.

Hope this helps! :-)

You can get the plugin here: **[jQuery Cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)**

Comment: While this might work, and is in line with what the OP already has, it is not clear from what the OP has written that using a cookie is an appropriate way for the prior visit to be recorded, particularly from the point of view of running in a Chrome extension. In fact, unless the goal is to make that information available to the webpage's server, using a cookie is a bad idea as it potentially interferes with the operation of the website.

Comment: @Makyen I am aware of this :-) however, until he decides to give _us_ more information. This is the best I can do

Comment: Actually, no.  You could have easily used Chrome extension specific methods to store the day information so as not to, potentially, impact the operation of whatever website the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Makyen I don't exactly have experience with _Chrome extension specific methods_, I'm doing this just from a JavaScript / jQuery point of view.

Comment: That was my expectation. However, even if you were not going to use [`chrome.storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) (storage location specific to that Chrome extension) then, it would have been better to use localStorage (local to the machine viewing the webpage) than a cookie (sent to server), and a key for the information that is longer than `day` so it has less chance to conflict with whatever the webpage is doing. The extension and web page are separate. The extension should not do things which might impact the webpage unless that is the *intent* of the action.

Comment: Hi @CaelanGrgurovic , Thank you for your answer. can you please tell me how can I install jQuery Cookie Plugin into chrome extension.